# Unable to click on link using selenium and getting an error

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my problem:

[image: Screenshot]

I am unable to click on a the input type button (Screenshot - indicator 3) to download a file, I do see the onclick function but not sure why its not clicking. If I use action.move_by_offset(1820,215).click().perform() I am able to click on the export but this is just a bandaid fix. I created a script to click on other parts of the webpage (Screenshot - indicator 1) which works fine. When create the script to click on this area (Screenshot - indicator 2) I get the error (see below). I have tried driver.find_element_by_xpath, driver.find_element(By.XPATH), driver.find_element_by_css_selector,  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR) along side with webdriverwait and I had no luck. Below I have included a clip of the HTML code, the code I am using in python and the error that I receive. If someone can point me to any documentation or have an ideas that would be amazing.

HTML:

```
    <input type="button"        
    name="ctl00$ctl00$BodyContent$BodyContent$FilterUsersControl$UserGrid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ExportToExcelButton"
    value=" " 
    onclick="if(!$find('ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_BodyContent_FilterUsersControl_UserGrid_ctl00').exportToExcel())
    return false;
    __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$BodyContent$BodyContent$FilterUsersControl$UserGrid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ExportToExcelButton','')"
    id="ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_BodyContent_FilterUsersControl_UserGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ExportToExcelButton" 
    title="Export to Excel" class="rgExpXLS">
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
link = 'https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='//xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/Python/Script/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(20)
action = ActionChains(driver)
export_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_BodyContent_FilterUsersControl_UserGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ExportToExcelButton"]')
export_btn.click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/Python/Script/update_UserList.py", line 42, in <module>
    export_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_BodyContent_FilterUsersControl_UserGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ExportToExcelButton"]')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_BodyContent_FilterUsersControl_UserGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ExportToExcelButton"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

```
export_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'BodyContent_BodyContent_FilterUsersControl_UserGrid_']")
```

the one you are trying looks dynamic ID, I have tried to extract the static data from it.

Also make sure that it should not be in any `iframe`.

Comment: I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type="button" and @title="Export to Excel"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77) Is there a way for me to send you the source code because this HTML file is 663 lines of code.

Comment: Did u check for iframes ? Is it inside it ?

Comment: Yes it is but how do I go about figuring out what index the iframe is in...I think i only see one. iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe") and then use iframes .get_attribute("src") as mine is this <iframe _ngcontent-hml-c61="" src="/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx.aspx"></iframe>

Comment: directly use css selector to switch `iframe[src=' src path']`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say definitively without seeing the source for the whole page, but in general you might consider using a different attribute in your xpath, or being more specific about the node you're looking for in your xpath. For example, something like this might not be *the* answer, but it might lead to better questions!

```python
export_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="button" and @title="Export to Excel"]')
```

Comment: I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type="button" and @title="Export to Excel"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)